# How can i get the type name value of an object as a string?

Tags: c#

I know it's simple.  I can't find it any where.

I want something like:

```
    string MyString = object.GetType;
```

I know that it wont work as written but how do I get the type value into a string.

Thanks for your indulgence,
Charles

Comment: You *know* that it won't work as written? What else did you find out when you came to know that? Did you type that code into your IDE? When you typed obj.GetType, did you notice it was a method with a return type? Did you explore the members of the return type for perhaps a string property that might contain things such as the name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
string myString = object.GetType().ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few properties. If you have the studio, the intellisense should give you what you want.

You can try also:

```
string myString = myObj.GetType().Name;
string myString2 = myObj.GetType().Fullname;  // Should give you the full type name including namespace
```

Comment: This seems like the proper course, since you'll usually want the fully-qualified name of a type.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the compile-time type of the object:

`string myString = typeof(object).Name;`

If you need to use the runtime type of an object:

`string myString = someInstance.GetType().Name;`